# how can we rewrite by Programing?

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I want to rewrite my URLs.  Currently I am using the Query String in lots of places in my project, but my client wants to hide the Query Strings.  How can I do this by Programing?

Comment: You should just google "URL Rewriting ASP.NET" (There are lots of resources out there) then come back here if you have specific implementation problems

Comment: You need to provide details of your site structure & examples of URLs you need to rewrite. You may be able to do this by writing rewrite rules in .htaccess.

Comment: i checked in google but most of use static implement in web.config, i want dyncamic result

Comment: Dear .htaccess work only for PHP

Comment: my URL Structure is not fix, i just want o hide query string

Comment: @skjaidev: I'm guessing MS stack, so .htaccess probably isn't the way to go.

Comment: yah i don't know why people give down vote without know anything

Comment: they up the vote and in future check the question and then down the vote

Comment: Well....the question is down-voted because it's worded very poorly, doesn't provide any specific information on what you're trying to accomplish, doesn't provide examples, is generally difficult to understand and is unlikely to be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [**URL Rewrite Module**](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/) - you won't have to touch your application at all.

> The Microsoft URL Rewrite module 2.0 includes the following key features:
>
> - **Rules-based URL rewriting engine.** Rewrite rules define the    logic used to analyze request URLs and map them to rewite URLs when
>     the request URL matches a defined rule. Web server and site
>     administrators can use rewrite rule sets to define URL rewriting
>     logic.
> - **Regular expression pattern matching.** Rewrite rules can use regular    expression syntax for pattern matching as defined in
>     ECMA-262.
> - **Wildcard pattern matching.** Rewrite rules can use wildcard syntax for    pattern matching.
> - **Global and distributed rewrite rules.** URL Rewrite uses global rules    to define server-wide URL rewriting logic. These rules are
>     defined    within the applicationHost.config file, and they supercede
>     rules    configured at lower levels in the configuration hierarchy.
>     The module    also uses distributed rules to define URL rewrite logic
>     specific to a    particular configuration scope. This type of rule can
>     be defined on    any configuration level by using Web.config files.
> - **Access to server variables and HTTP headers.** Server variables and    HTTP headers provide additional information about current HTTP 
>     requests. This information can be used to configure rewrite rules or
>     to compose the output URL.

Comment: Thanks but my client have windows 2003 server with IIS 6, so i don't have any want , i just have to done it via write the code